# How can I make a build of an app that requires macos?

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab

We are using Gitlab CI, how do we do a build of an application within it that requires it to be build on **macos**?
I'm talking about the Electon JS application. I have successfully built the windows and linux versions, but the macos requires the ****dmg-license** module** to be installed, it is only installed on *os: darwin*

```
build_electron_win:
  stage: build
  image: electronuserland/builder:wine
  variables:
    ENV_FILE: $ENV_DEV
  script:
    - mv ggem/dist ggem/apps
    - cd ggem
    - npm install -g npm@8.1.3 && npm install -g nx && npm install
    - nx run launcher-electron:lint
    - nx run launcher-electron:build:production
    - nx run launcher-electron:make-win
    - nx run launcher-electron:make-linux
    - nx run launcher-electron:make-mac   -- that is the command which supposed to build mac binary
  dependencies:
    - build_frontend_dev
  needs:
    - build_frontend_dev
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - ggem/dist/executables/Launcher*
      - ggem/dist/executables/linux-unpacked/ggem
```